# What's the use case of TableCell?

Tags: flutter

I can show widgets as children of TableRow. They are displayed correctly. What's the use case of `TableCell` in flutter?

```dart
TableRow(children: [
      widget1,
      widget2,
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableCell is a widget that can control how a child of a Table is aligned.
which means position of a child inside a cell...

Working example :

```
TableRow(children: [
    TableCell(
    verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
    child: Text('Soccer',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center)),Column(children: <Widget>[Text('Ronaldo'), Text('Messi')])
```

see below document to get more idea about this...

https://medium.com/flutter-community/table-in-flutter-beyond-the-basics-8d31b022b451